# How to test method that wrapping another method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

Let's imagine having class (written in Java-like pseudocode):

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    public List<Element> getElementsThatContains(String str) {
        return this.getElementsThatContains(new Set<String> { str });
    }

    public List<Element> getElementsThatContains(Set<String> strs) {

        ...

    }
}
```

First of all - I have `getElementsThatContains(Set<String> strs)` properly 100% covered.

How should I cover `getElementsThatContains(String str)`:

- Should I copy (almost) all the tests but with call to `getElementsThatContains(String str)`?
- Should I just make one test
  method that check if results from first and second methods are same
  (with same incoming data)?
- Should I refactor my code so I do not have
  such a situation? (If yes, how?)

Comment: I would just write for getElementsThatContains(String str), which will cover for next call as well

Comment: @YogenRai, there is logic specific for input of set. You suggest have all "Set-independent" login to be tested by calling method#1 and all "Set-dependent" by calling method#2? I can see how it can be confusing for people who will read my code.

Comment: If there is input specific logic on second method, then you can write for both input scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should cover both methods. The reason for having unit tests is the safety net, when the code is refactored. For example, Someone might refactor the implementation of 'getElementsThatContains(String str)' and it will always return an empty List. Despite getElementsThatContains(Set strs) has 100% coverage those tests won't catch this.

No, you should not make one test method that check if results from first and second methods are same. This is generally considered a bad practice. Moreover, if there is a bug in one method, your test would just check the other method returns same incorrect result.

No, you should not copy all the tests, because the test cases for each method would be different. The arguments for the methods are different. So you will have different test cases for each, despite that underneath the same method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should *test* both methods, and you should use distinct test cases for each method.

But you should care less for your *line coverage*.
Don't get me wrong here! It is important to keep the line coverage high. But it is more important to have 100% *behavior coverage*. And if you come across untested lines your question should be: "*Is this untested code needed (i.e. what requirement does it implement) or is it obsolete?"*.

When we write our tests with *line coverage* in mind we tend to focus on the *implementation details* of our code under test. In consequence our tests are likely to fail when we change this *implementation details* (e.g. during *refactoring*). But our tests should only fail if the tested *behavior* changes and not when we change the way this behavior is achieved.